# ActiveModel doesn't reload association after its creation. Is this behaviour expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

So I have what I consider complex associations in my application.

I have an `Account` model which implements Devise and handles authentication.
Then, there are many different models that are profiles and for the sake of simplicity here I'll reduce them to one: `Profile`.
Finally, there's the `Address` model which is associated to `Profile`.

Instead of explaining how the associations work, I rather show you some code:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :account
  validates :profile, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile # Note: sets :autosave => true
end
```

The `:profile` polymorphic relation is necessary as I have different kinds of account profiles. I also need the `:inverse_of` on it because I need to access `Account` instances from `Profile` ones even if they're new records.

So here's an example of a `Profile`: it has an `Address` associated to it.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account, as: :profile
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
  validates :address, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address # Note: sets :autosave => true
end
```

Finally the `Address` model which belongs to a `Profile`.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The problem with this is that Rails seems to keep an old version of the profile associated to the Account. I guess it's doing it right as I used the :inverse_of option. But I'm not sure.

Run the following code:

```
account = Account.new
account.profile = Profile.new
account.profile.build_address
account.save
account.profile.address #=> nil
account.profile.reload.address #=> #<Address id: 21, created_at: "2013-11-22 13:47:27", updated_at: "2013-11-22 13:47:27", addressable_id: 21, addressable_type: "Profile">
```

See? account.profile.address is `nil`.
If you reload the profile attached to the account, (i.e. `account.profile.reload`) you'll see that the `address` record was actually saved. But unless profile is reloaded, `account` doesn't know about it.

From what I observed, here's the order of records creation:

1. profile is saved to the database: great! now we have its `id`.
2. address is saved to the database and sets the `profile_type` and `profile_id`.
3. account is saved to the database and sets the `profile_type` and `profile_id`.

Shouldn't `account.profile` be reloaded after `address`' creation automatically?

Here's the best solution I've found so far (added to the Account model):

```
  before_create -> { profile.reload }
```

I didn't like it though as I think there's maybe a native way of doing it.

PS: I'm running Rails 3.2.14, Ruby 2.0. I've also tested the examples above with Rails 4.0.1, same results.

Comment: Weird. What happens if you add the reciprocal inverse_of to the Profile class? `has_one :account, as: :profile, inverse_of: :profile`

Comment: I've just tried it, @WizardofOgz but it didn't solve the problem.
I don't even know how :inverse_of is working in the first place. According to Rails documentation it shouldn't work with polymorphic relations.